# rails: how to check admin user for setting up a route?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I need to set up a route that is only valid if the logged in user is admin (user.admin?) using devise.  I'm doing this for sidekiq, but the question is valid for any similar use.

Here is my route code:

```
class AdminConstraint
  def matches?(request)
    !request.session['warden.user.user.key'].nil? and request.session['warden'].user.admin?
  end
end

require 'sidekiq/web'
mount Sidekiq::Web => '/sidekiq', :constraints => AdminConstraint.new
```

I got this code from the sidekiq wiki:  https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Monitoring
I tried the code they posted, which didn't work so I made some modifications as I just posted.   The code above doesn't work as user evaluates to nil.

What is the correct *secure* way to deal with this?

thanks for any help!

Answer (score 12):

If you are using devise to authenticate users, what you need to do is as follows:

Inside your routes.rb file, replace this line:

```
mount Sidekiq::Web => '/sidekiq', :constraints => AdminConstraint.new
```

with this block:

```
authenticate :user, lambda { |u| u.has_role? :admin } do
    mount Sidekiq::Web => '/sidekiq'
end
```

What the block does, is telling to your devise mechanism to check first if the user is authenticated (the `authenticate` method is a devise method), and also that the user has the admin role (which the lambda block checks), before defining the route to the sidekiq UI.
This way, only users with an admin role will be able to access this route. Other users will get routing error in development and 404 error in production.

One more thing, the `has_role?` method is a rolify gem which in my case I use, but you can replace it with any other method/query that checks if the user is admin.

Comment: It's a great answer, still valid in 2020! and in case you have and `admin` column in your `users` table, something like this should work: `authenticated :user, lambda { |u| u.admin? }`

Comment: actually here are the docs covering this https://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/ActionDispatch%2FRouting%2FMapper:authenticated

Answer (score 0):

You're not really trying to change the route depending on who the user is (I'm not even sure if it's possible in rails without a lot of hacking), you're trying to *authorize* a user's action.

There are several good authorization libraries.  Personally I like [CanCan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan), but there are many others.

Answer (score 0):

if you are doing any type of filtering in the controller for devise you can use the helpers

```
class ###Controller < ApplicationController

  before_filter: :authenticate_admin!

def index
end
```

or whichever devise model you are trying to allow access for i.e

```
before_filter: :authenticate_user!
before_filter: :authenticate_author!
```

like bdares said. you can use the CanCan gem for authorization if the helper methods in devise isn't enough

hope it helps!